# How to read an xml file in Java class without giving a user name path an just with directory path(" /A/B/src/main/resources/x.xml")?

Tags: java, file

```
Public class M{
    File file = new File("/Users/Me/A/B/src/main/resources/x.xml");
}
```

I would like to write something like:

```
File file = new File("/A/B/src/main/resources/x.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to access `~/A/B/src/main/resources/x.xml`, i.e. a path under the *current* user's home directory, you need to read the home directory from `user.home` and append your path to it:

```
File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/A/B/src/main/resources/x.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not where your file is.

Putting the slash ("/") at the front of your filepath indicates to the file system that this is an "absolute" path, in other words, that A is a directory in the root directory of the file system.

You can either get the system property to indicate where the user's home directory is, or, if something (your code or other code) sets the user's home directory as the default directory, then you could use "A/B/src/main/resources/x.xml" (no slash at the beginning), which indicates to the file system to start from the default directory instead of from the root.